# Implicit resolution in descendants of associated types to avoid import tax

Tags: scala, implicits

```
class JavaRxObservable
class MyObservable extends JavaRxObservable

object MyObservable {
  implicit class ObservablePimp(o: JavaRxObservable) {
    def flatMapPimp: JavaRxObservable = ... 
  }
}

def api: JavaRxObservable = new MyObservable

api.flatMapPimp // is this possible without import statement ?
```

Note that it is not possible to create a companion object to **third party type** JavaRxObservable. And **since my `api` method must return `JavaRxObservable`** type because of its combinatory nature (`MyObservable#map` would return `JavaRxObservable`), it is a major drawback in API design because you are forcing people to read documentation that they gotta import stuff to use your api. Not even declaration in package object helps if it is meant to be API used by third parties.

Comment: You "gotta import stuff" to use *any* API. That's just life ...

Comment: Yeah, `import com.example.Foo` ... but not `import com.example.Foo; import com.example.Foo.ObservablePimp` - that's just hard life :-)

Comment: import com.example.Foo._

Comment: That's even more awful

Comment: I disagree. I think, what's really awful is when things happen magically. Like, when a new method appears on a well-known standard library object,without even a hint at where it is defined or how to get rid of it. Implicits are bad enough in that respect ... but if they worked without even have to be imported into scope, that would be just crazy :)

Comment: You sound like you haven't seen those bunches of jira and github issues : "It doesn't work"; Closed : "You must import `com.example.whatever._`". I'm sick of these, its a recurring problem and import hell. If somebody is new to scala, it will just all be a magic to him, import statements doesn't make it less of a magic. They just prolong the agony of learning how it works. This freedom of declaring implicits all over, importing them everywhere is imho wrong, but that's another discussion:-) Imports should be used for overriding defaults not for using pimped classes or ad-hoc polymorphism

Comment: Import statements may not be making it less magic, but, at least, they give you a hint at where to start looking for the definitions of the "enhancer" methods that got magically attached to your objects.

Comment: I guess that people who use IDE have a different opinion than those who don't.

Comment: What does it have to do with IDE (I don't use one, so you might know something here that I just don't ;))?

Comment: I was reacting on your last message. IDE tells you exactly where the [definitions are located](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Working+with+Scala+Implicit+Conversions)

Comment: well, yeah ... Call it a personal idiosyncrasy, but I despise source code that requires additional software to be *read*. You can't rely on IDE always being available to the reader of your code. They could be browsing github, or grepsource, or use some other way to navigate your source remotely.  Also, IDE is no silver bullet anyway.  Consider a function `def foo(bar: Int)(implicit context: SuperDuperContext)`, that's called somewhere like `foo(1)`. Can you tell what the `context` parameter is and where it comes from? Does IDE help?